# Bootstrap modal popup and also call a page change

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and am calling the modal popup window.  Works great.  I'd like to add the ability to also call a new/change page.  Would I use JS or is it possible to add to the href?

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-gallery="dining-room" href="#galleryModal">
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of href="#galleryModal", point it to the actual remote URL.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-gallery="dining-room" 
  href="yourRemoteURL" data-target="#modal-Container">
```

Try this as well:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="yourRemoteURL" id="clicker" role="button" class="btn">Clicker</a>
<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    var $modal = $('#modal');
    $('#clicker').on('click', function (e) { /** Call the modal manually */
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $modal.html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="' + url + '"></iframe>');
        $modal.modal({
            show: true
        });
    });


    $modal.on('hide', function () {
        $modal.empty() /** Clean up */
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Cp3WY/

Comment: Thanks, close.. but the remoteURL isn't called.

Comment: Is the URL you're calling external?

Comment: the url would be relative, basically a call back to index.php.  Thanks for your help!